# iOS - centralizing CAGradientLayer into parent UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, calayer

I have a `bgLayer: CAGradientLayer` **with bigger dimensions** then it's parent view `bgView`. The layer is being inserted correctly using `bgView.layer.insertSublayer`, but I can't create the frame of my `bgLayer` centralized with my smaller `bgView`.

How could I centralize my `bgLayer` into my `bgView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you mean...

Larger Gradient view centered on smaller UIView. First image is with `.clipsToBounds = true`, second image `.false.`:

[image][image]

Both images use the same view size: `100 x 100` and the same gradient size: `150 x 150`. You can paste this code into a Playground page to see how it works.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))

container.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.5, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 150 x 150 frame for the gradient layer
        let gFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)

        // 100 x 100 frame for the View
        let vFrame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)

        let v = UIView(frame: vFrame)
        self.view.addSubview(v)

        // add a border to the UIView so we can see its frame
        v.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

        // set up the Gradient Layer
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

        // set the initial size of the gradient frame
        gradient.frame = gFrame

        // center the gradient frame over (or inside, if smaller) the view frame
        gradient.frame.origin.x = (v.frame.size.width - gradient.frame.size.width) / 2
        gradient.frame.origin.y = (v.frame.size.height - gradient.frame.size.height) / 2

        // add the gradient layer to the view
        v.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

        // set to true to clip the gradient layer
        // set to false to allow the gradient layer to extend beyond the view
        v.clipsToBounds = true

    }

}

let vc = ViewController()
container.addSubview(vc.view)
```

Comment: Great! I was confused about the formula to center them both.